# form validation error on php script?

Tags: php, html

Update: the form is not deleting special character like "<"

```
    <?php 
$name = $_POST["nombre"];



$data = test_input($name);

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;

}
```

the stripslashes should remove the / and the trim the Whitespace, but is not doing it is showing like pre tag of html

```
echo $data;
?>
```

Comment: In case you have a time, reading manual of PHP [variable scope](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is good tho.

Comment: why my scopes are right ? .-. ...

Comment: `$data` appears inside `test_input` function scope, not globally available. That proves you haven't read the link above, right?

Comment: u mean use $globals["data"] but is on the fcuntion ? function test_input($data)

Comment: From manual: _within user-defined functions a local function scope is introduced. Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local function scope._ It means you can't use `$data` or any other variables outside `test_input` function.

Comment: but data should be global, is declared $data = test_input($name);
 and then used on function like argument...

Comment: Yeah it should be global, after you edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: before was declared global too .-.

Comment: No, `$nombre` was.

Comment: right srry i forget, i changed nombre

Comment: @Pachi Please edit your question to explain what is "not working well". We cannot know what the correct or incorrect program code is if you don't tell us what's wrong and how the correct data should be.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is to remove the HTML tags from `$name` you need to use `strip tags`:

```
<?php 
function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = strip_tags($data);
    return $data;
}
$name = ' <script>addada</script>';
echo $data = test_input($name);
```